# Using Properties[] in Xamarin Applications

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Looking at a sample Xamarin application I see this code:

```
    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnSleep saving ResumeAtTodoId = " + ResumeAtTodoId);
        // the app should keep updating this value, to
        // keep the "state" in case of a sleep/resume
        Properties["ResumeAtTodoId"] = ResumeAtTodoId;
    }
```

In particular `Properties["ResumeAtTodoId"]`

In my application I have been using a static class like this to hold constants. But would it be better to user `Properties`.  Is this what is normally used?

```
namespace Japanese
{
    public static class AS
    {
        public static bool sac; // Score All Cards
        public static bool swt; // Show Word Type
```

Comment: In your case, the members in the static Class has a life only for a single session of application. If this is what you what then your Static Class is fine.
Use Application Properties if you want to have your data persisted even after you close the app. The good thing about Application properties is that, it auto saves the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application Properties dictionary is used for storing persistent data. If you want to use data only during one session you should most likely use static class. If you want to persist the data even when the application closes you should use persistent data storage. Read more about the Application Properties here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary

A good alternative to Xamarin Forms Properties dictionary is James Montemagnos Settings plugin which works on Xamarin native versions as well: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

Comment: Is the persistent data lost when an application update is made?

Comment: I don't think so. Not completely sure about iOS but I think it should hold the data until the application is uninstalled.